# How can I use NLP to parse recipe ingredients?

Tags: parsing, nlp

I need to parse recipe ingredients into amount, measurement, item, and description as applicable to the line, such as 1 cup flour, the peel of 2 lemons and 1 cup packed brown sugar etc. What would be the best way of doing this? I am interested in using python for the project so I am assuming using the nltk is the best bet but I am open to other languages.

Comment: Hey if you're still interested in recipe parsing, I've [open sourced](https://github.com/KitchenPC/core/) my implementation.  Maybe you'll find it useful!

Comment: I would have never expected to find this question here and someone actually answering it with a ready to use solution!

Answer (score 31):

I actually do this for my website, which is now part of an [open source project](https://github.com/KitchenPC/core) for others to use.

I wrote a blog post on my techniques, enjoy!

http://blog.kitchenpc.com/2011/07/06/chef-watson/

Comment: Is this program can extract ingredients from a sentence like “BEET JUICE AND BEET POWDER (FOR COLOR)”
from above sentence i need to extract “BEET JUICE”,”BEET POWER” ?

Comment: It does not.  But it's open source, so it can be improved or extended.

Answer (score 19):

*The New York Times* faced this problem when they were parsing their recipe archive. They used an NLP technique called linear-chain condition random field (CRF). This blog post provides a good overview:

- ["Extracting Structured Data From Recipes Using Conditional Random Fields"](https://open.blogs.nytimes.com/2015/04/09/extracting-structured-data-from-recipes-using-conditional-random-fields/)

They open-sourced their code, but quickly abandoned it. I maintain [the most up-to-date version](https://github.com/mtlynch/ingredient-phrase-tagger) of it and I [wrote a bit](https://mtlynch.io/resurrecting-1/) about how I modernized it.

If you're looking for a ready-made solution, several companies offer ingredient parsing as a service:

- [Zestful](https://zestfuldata.com/) (full disclosure: I'm the author)
- [Spoonacular](https://rapidapi.com/spoonacular/api/Recipe%20-%20Food%20-%20Nutrition/functions/Parse%20Ingredients)
- [Edamam](https://rapidapi.com/edamam/api/edamam-nutrition-analysis)

Comment: I'm curious, since I've occasionally thought of turning mine into a "SaaS" solution but don't know if there's a market for it - have you ever gotten a paying customer?

Comment: I have, but not enough to make the project a viable business. Fun, though! I [write about my stats publicly](https://mtlynch.io/solo-developer-year-2/#zestfulhttpszestfuldatacom) if you're interested.

To date, I've made about $5.8k on Zestful. Most of it is from a handful of customers who need to do one-time processing of a large dataset.

Comment: That's super cool!  I [blogged](https://blog.kitchenpc.com/) about all my adventures as well writing KitchenPC.  I ran into the same conclusion as you; super fun to write, but probably not a big enough market to really get anywhere big with it..

Comment: Thanks mtlynch. I looked at your api, looks great the pricing is too high for what I would be able to use it for.

Answer (score 5):

I guess this is a few years out, but I was thinking of doing something similar myself and came across this, so thought I might have a stab at it in case it is useful to anyone else in f

Even though you say you want to parse free test, most recipes have a pretty standard format for their recipe lists: each ingredient is on a separate line, exact sentence structure is rarely all that important.  The range of vocab is relatively small as well.

One way might be to check each line for words which might be nouns and words/symbols which express quantities.  I think WordNet may help with seeing if a word is likely to be a noun or not, but I've not used it before myself.  Alternatively, you could use http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cookbook:Ingredients as a word list, though again, I wouldn't know exactly how comprehensive it is.

The other part is to recognise quantities.  These come in a few different forms, but few enough that you could probably create a list of keywords.  In particular, make sure you have good error reporting.  If the program can't fully parse a line, get it to report back to you what that line is, along with what it has/hasn't recognised so you can adjust your keyword lists accordingly.

Aaanyway, I'm not guaranteeing any of this will work (and it's almost certain not to be 100% reliable) but that's how I'd start to approach the problem

Answer (score 3):

This is an incomplete answer, but you're looking at writing up a free-text parser, which as you know, is non-trivial :)

Some ways to cheat, using knowledge specific to cooking:

1. Construct lists of words for the "adjectives" and "verbs", and filter against them

   1. measurement units form a closed set, using words and abbreviations like {L., c, cup, t, dash}
   2. instructions -- cut, dice, cook, peel.  Things that come after this are almost certain to be ingredients
2. Remember that you're mostly looking for nouns, and you can take a labeled list of non-nouns (from WordNet, for example) and filter against them.

If you're more ambitious, you can look in the [NLTK Book](http://www.nltk.org/book) at the chapter on parsers.

Good luck!  This sounds like a mostly doable project!

Answer (score -1):

Can you be more specific what your input is? If you just have input like this:

```
1 cup flour
2 lemon peels
1 cup packed brown sugar
```

It won't be too hard to parse it without using any NLP at all.

Comment: There are some examples above, specifically the peel of 2 lemons. It is going to be free typed text so it could be just about anything that is a valid amount and item.

Comment: if you really want to be able to handle "anything" then you need a human to do the parsing, or it's an AI-level problem.  That's the nature of the beast when it comes to text parsing.  Make assumptions for normal cases, and assume that edge cases will fail.